# LDAP with kerberos authenication in Java

Tags: java, oracle, ldap, kerberos, gssapi

I'm having some problems with using kerberos authenication for a client on an LDAP directory.

My program is written in java and I'm using the GSSAPI to handle kerberosv5 Auth.

I strictly followed the oracle tutorial that you can find at this link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/gssapi.html,
but when I launch the program, it throws an Ecception, saying "No LoginModule configurated for LoginClass".

Did anyone have this problem before? how did you fix this?
Fore sure the problem is not about the LDAP connection (if i use the "simple" authentication, it works correclty)

Comment: Have you considered trying the UnboundID LDAP SDK for Java instead of JNDI (see [Javadocs](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/GSSAPIBindRequest.html) and [Maven link](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.unboundid%7Cunboundid-ldapsdk%7C3.1.1%7Cjar)). Disclaimer: I work for UnboundID.

Comment: It sounds like you renamed the GssExample class  as "LoginClass" and need to update the gsseg_jaas.conf file?

Comment: Of course I updated the name in the config file... I'll post the code later so you can see if there's something wrong in it.